# Rails database add column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When creating a model in Rails, I forgot to add a column `amount` that I want. How can I add it to the model later?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a new migration via the console with:

```
rails g migration add_amount_to_items
```

This should create a migration something like this:

```
class AddAmountToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # add_column table_name, :column_name, :column_type
    add_column :items, :amount, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello. I did like this "rails g migration add_priority_to_article" - but the migration file that was generated had no instruction... instead I used "priority:integer" (ending the g-command) and it worked

Answer (score 10):

The lazy way:

```
rails g migration add_amount_to_items amount:integer
```

Comment: Hi thank you @WeGoingNowhere - what is the proper, dilligent way that will save grief long term. what if you don't want 'quick and dirty'

Comment: And don't forget to run the migration: bin/rake db:migrate